# WordPress theme options tabs

Tags: options, tabs

It is possible to create tabs in admin panel in Theme options like in Theme? Please see this screenshot:

[image: http://i33.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0322/7c/a22f2c8bc821b2249fb0bc4ed328307c.png]

I can't find any official documentation about adding admin tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress includes many js libraries in `\wp-includes\js`  and in `wp-admin\js`. You can browse through them and choose which one you want, including jQuery tabs.

You can use it in your theme by using this function, http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

To figure out how to use the tabs, you would read about it here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: What about clean without js?

Comment: You can create CSS tabs, but I don't understand what you mean by "clean".